# list all files with extensions in a directory and give count of each such files in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I need all the files in any particular directory (/home/docs/) with the count of each such files categorized as per their extensions.

The output should be like:

```
.mp3 - 10 
.ksh - 15 
.doc - 20 
.xls - 3
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
ls -1|awk -F'.' 'NF>1{a[$NF]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}'
```

this will exclude directories and filename without a `dot`, also using single awk process.

Comment: Thanks Kent. 
This is the exact output I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: it does not cope well with filenames with spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -name "*?.*" -type f -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I"--" sh -c 'fn="--" ; echo "${fn##*.}"' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"-",$1}'
```

Comment: You may want to explain that long command so that it is easier to understand it.